# find which user uploaded magento product

Tags: magento2, user-roles, user

We gave admin panel password to many employees of our company.

but created different users and different roles for each employee.

Is there any option to find out which "user" uploaded or edited a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not out of the box. This is a EE feature.

The alternative is, we (firegento, not me personally :)) just build a module for it: https://github.com/firegento/firegento-adminmonitoring

Comment: i will try and let you know.....

Comment: also is it allows to find  information before installing this extension

Comment: you mean more than the long long readme? I don't think so. But you should install it on your development system before deploying it to live. NEVER install any plugin directly into the live system